# I am using google Map fragment twice in my android app and getting this error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

> here is my logcat screen shot i am getting this error please tell me how to use google map fragment two time?

[image: logcat screen shot]

Comment: Error saying **duplicate id** have you defined both fragment the same id???

Comment: without the code is impossible to help you.
You can either have put a duplicate id for the map (as Clairvoyant suggested) so you have to change the id of the second map, OR you maybe copied the code to lookup the mapfragment and put the same parent for two different maps (the log needs the code to understand).

Comment: duplicate id is not the problem i have tried withe different ids but its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

How do you add your fragment?

The best way to do it is:

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: Please add more code then. At least give use your xml file.